# Чат-бот самообучающийся по ответам оператора

Tags: python, aiogram, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Всем привет!
Делаю проект, а именно - чат-бот телеграмм. Хочу туда внедрить чат с техподдержкой, но при этом, чтобы автоматизировать работу операторов мне нужно сделать так, чтобы бот обучался по вопросам пользователей и ответам оператором, т.е, что я имею ввиду(П-пользователь, О-Оператор, Ч-чат-бот):

---

П: Как зарегистрироваться на сайте?
Ч: Подождите, передаю ваш вопрос специалисту.
*Тут чат-бот пересылает сообщение оператору*
О: Нужно нажать на кнопку войти, ввести корпоративный логин и пароль
*Бот пересылает ответ пользователю*
Ч: Нужно нажать на кнопку войти, ввести корпоративный логин и пароль. Я ответил на ваш вопрос?
*Сессия завершается*
П2:Как войти в личный кабинет?
*Чат-бот уже знает, как отвечать на этот вопрос, поэтому сразу отвечает, не пересылая ответ оператору
Ч: Нужно нажать на кнопку войти, ввести корпоративный логин и пароль. Я ответил на ваш вопрос?(А если здесь пользователь ответил нет, то пересылается оператору)

---

По сути, это такой же чат-бот, как в банках различных, но я поискал информацию в интернете и нашел крайне мало, пишу на Python используя aiogram.
Прошу помочь с информацией, какие библиотеки использовать, возможно, есть какие-то примеры работ подобных, возможно ли это вообще реализовать. Просветите, пожалуйста. Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: а сообщение оператору куда отправляется? тоже в телеграмм?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал только `aiogram`.

Создал бы список с вопросами (чтобы знать, какие вопросы задавались) и словарь с вопросами, значение которых - ответ на вопрос, а потом при вопросе пользователя узнавал бы, есть ли такой вопрос в списке (если нет - задать вопрос оператору, получить ответ, добавить вопрос в список и в словарь (туда уже с ответом) и ответить пользователю, если есть - ответить значением вопроса из словаря (если ответ не удовлетворил - делать тоже самое, как будто вопроса нет))

Вообще, этот алгоритм можно и нужно дорабатывать (к примеру, можно научить бота объединять вопросы в один, скажем, по ключевым словам и т.д.). Но для начала, я думаю, сойдет

Comment: Вот я про ключевые слова думал, а не подскажите, есть ли какие-то библиотеки готовые, которые могут по ключевым словам выделять похожий вопрос?

Comment: @agfn Я думаю, здесь можно использовать библиотеку `spaCy`